# AWK column matching pattern

Tags: linux, awk

I'm trying to write a command to find lines where specific column in a csv file that matches the pattern. I'm struggling with pattern matching for that column

Task: **Print lines where 5th column(col5date) is June, July or Aug 2022**

Sample csv file:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5date | col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcd | asdd | 2022 | asdd | 7/4/22 | something |
| abcd | asdd | 2022 | asdd | 10/9/22 | something |
| abcd | asdd | 2022 | asdd | 12/12/20 | something |
| abcd | asdd | 2020 | asdd | 9/1/19 | something |
| abcd | asdd | 2020 | asdd | 9/1/22 | something |
| abcd | asdd | 2021 | asdd | 9/22/19 | something |
| abcd | asdd | 2021 | asdd | 2/16/22 | something |
| abcd | asdd | 2021 | asdd | 6/16/22 | something |

Expected output after command: first and last lines since the dates are june and july.

My awk command:

```
cat file | awk -F'|' '$5 ~ /(6|7|8)\/*\/22$/'
```

In the pattern `"/(6|7|8)\/*\/22$/"` I'm trying to say
m/d/Y - m is either 6, 7 or 8
* - for day
22$ - for year and column ends

Comment: you've stated the file is `csv` (comma-delimited), but showing us a table (tab-delimted?) while the `awk` code specifies a pipe (`|`) delimiter; it would help to see the actual data (`cat file` and cut-n-paste into question with 'code' format

Comment: please update the question to show the expected output

Comment: as currently coded the `\/*` says to match on zero or more `/` characters; assuming you want to match on zero or more characters between a pair of `/` then consider: `\/.*\/` (note the period)

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples and attempts please try following `awk` code. Here is the complete [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OEZ27B/1) for used regex with explanation. Code here matches June month's exact date range(since its date can't go more than 30), same thing with July and August it will match date range till 31 only for line of those months.

```bash
awk '$5~/^6\/([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|30)\/[0-9]{2}$|^[7-8]\/([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\/[0-9]{2}$/'  Input_file
```

Comment: I was thinking about writing the full pattern for 3 months ++

Comment: `[12]?[1-9]|[123]0`

Answer (score 3):

This part of the pattern `\/*` repeats 0+ times a forward slash instead of matching days.

You might narrow the match for the days part to digits (which still not validate a valid date), and you can omit the `cat` command.

```
awk -F'|' '$5 ~ /^[678]\/([1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/22$/' file
```

If you are using a comma as a separator, then use `awk -F,`

**Output**

```
abcd|asdd|2022|asdd|7/4/22|something
abcd|asdd|2021|asdd|6/16/22|something
```

Answer (score 3):

assuming the data format is correct, you can eliminate formatting matches.

```
$ awk -F, '$5~/^[6-8].*22$/' file
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear (to me) how the input file is delimited so for demonstration purposes I'll assume comma delimited:

```
$ cat file
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5date,col6
abcd,asdd,2022,asdd,7/4/22,something
abcd,asdd,2022,asdd,10/9/22,something
abcd,asdd,2022,asdd,12/12/20,something
abcd,asdd,2020,asdd,9/1/19,something
abcd,asdd,2020,asdd,9/1/22,something
abcd,asdd,2021,asdd,9/22/19,something
abcd,asdd,2021,asdd,2/16/22,something
abcd,asdd,2021,asdd,6/16/22,something
```

One `awk` idea that allows the user to dynamically designate the month(s) and year to search for:

```
awk -F',' -v mon='6,7,8' -v year="22" '        # define input delimiter as comma; OP provides comma-delimited list of numerical months along with desired year

BEGIN  { split(mon,a,",")                      # split input variable "mon" on commas and place results into array a[]
         for (i in a)                          # loop through indices of array a[] and ...
             months[a[i]]                      # build new array where numerical months are the indices of the array months[]
       }
FNR==1 { print; next }                         # print header row then skip to next line of input
       { split($5,a,"/")                       # split 5th field on "/" delimiter and place results into array a[]
         if (a[1] in months && a[3] == year)   # if a[1] is an index in the months[] array and a[3] matches the desired year then ...
            print                              # print current line to stdout
       }
' file
```

This generates:

```
$ . ./dates.awk
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5date,col6
abcd,asdd,2022,asdd,7/4/22,something
abcd,asdd,2021,asdd,6/16/22,something
```

Answer (score 3):

if you don't have any other dates in each row :

> ```
> gawk -b '1 < NF' FS='[,|][6-8][/][^/]+[/]22[,|]'
> ```

if you're VERY certain there are no erroneously formatted dates in the input, then even simpler :

> ```
> mawk '/[,|][6-8][^|]+22[,|]/'
> ```

I usually prefer using square brackets for regex special char escape, as it delineates boundaries a lot clearer visually than `\\\\\\whiskey\\\\\\tango\\\\\\foxtrot\\\\` chaos in many `regex`es, with the added bonus of not having to worry about how many backslashes being "eaten" by each extra layer it's passed through before actually executed by `awk`

e.g. forward slash `"/"` ::

> ```
> for command line assignments --
> ```

- `mawk`'s okay with typing -  `\/` , while
- `gawk / nawk` need a pair — `\\/` ,

> ```
> for standard double quoted string from —
> ```

**- `"[/]"` is all-awk variants-friendly**

> ```
> for regex in the open `/…/` form ::
> ```

- `mawk/gawk` okay with `/…[/]…/` while
- `nawk` *insists* on that extra backslash `/…[\/]…/`, which somewhat defeats the readability rationale for opting for `[…]` over `\/\/\\+\\/\\\]\\[\\\\……`

Answer (score 2):

Like this, assuming the file is `csv` (commas) and not `tsv` (tabs) or even `|` (pipe) separated file:

```
awk -F, '$5 ~ /^(6|7|8)\/.*\/22$/' file
```

But there's no matching line in your sample input

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like

```
awk -F, '$5 ~ "^[6-8]/[^/]+/22$"'
```

so you don't have to escape '/` and also can reject malformed dates